# Why does the character I placed on the ground look like he is floating?

Tags: rendering

I created this scene but when rendered, why does the character look like he's floating even though he is flat on the ground?

[image]

Comment: When you stand on the ground your shadow reaches your foot. But in this case the shadow's quality so poor it doesn't look connected.

Comment: If you're working with Eevee, lamps have an option called "contact shadow" (in the shadow section of the lamp properties).

Comment: Is contact shadow how i improve the shadow? Or are there other ways?